# how to intercept xamarin mobile application traffic using burp?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, burp

I've set up my Iphone to intercept traffic using burp. Im able to intercept traffic for web browser requests and non xamarin applications. However im not able to intercept xamarin applications traffic. However the application is working fine sending and receiving traffic but burp is not intercepting the request. Can anyone tell me how this is possible. Is it because burp is not able to see the traffic or xamarin application is not connecting via proxy? Also how to intercept traffic for xamarin applications.

Comment: Unless you explicitly opted out of using secure connections, your app will use SSL. That is a bit harder to detect. If you want to actually look into your requests you will have to install a certificate. You could have a look at [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) which helps you with that.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, What if I want to secure the URLs links of the images that I am sending to the user? The interception is hard since I will be using HTTPS and I can even encrypt the body, but the image will be called through url anyway!

Comment: It sounds like Xamarin is using its own HTTP stack that doesn't follow the proxy settings. You may be able to use [this technique](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2899081-using-burp-s-invisible-proxy-settings-to-test-a-non-proxy-aware-thick-client-application) to intercept the traffic.